# How to Connect Visual Studio to Azure Website over Proxy server

Tags: azure, proxy

I recently deployed an ASP.NET MVC4 website to Azure website. However anytime I am on a proxy network, I wouldn't be able to connect to the services.

How to connect Visual Studio Azure SDK1.3 to the Azure Website Over proxy server. Below is error message:

`There was no endpoint listening at  https://management.core.windows.net/3e541adf-2b85-4ff1-b066-a40f11f6e4a6/services/?servicelist=WebSite&expandlist=Service that could accept the message`.

This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The remote name could not be resolved: 'management.core.windows.net'

Answer (score 1):

The very last line of the error says it all:

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'management.core.windows.net'

The proxy you are using blocks or has DNS resolution issues for the `management.core.windows.net` domain. There isn't much you can do about it, besides using another proxy or not using proxy at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to whitelist domains on your proxy, or know someone that can, you will want to whitelist ***management.core.windows.net***.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, it explains how to use a Port Bridge to get around your problem.

http://www.dotnetsolutions.co.uk/blog/connecting-to-sql-azure-without-changing-your-firewall